# How to get first n elements from map and put into another map?

Tags: apex, map, collection

I want to make a new map with first n elements from the existing map in apex.
Please help.

```
        Map<String, Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>> limitedMap = new Map<String, Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>>();
        Set<String> numberOfKeys = initialMap.keySet();
        if(initialMap.size() > requiredElements){
            for(Integer i = 0; i<requiredElements;i++){
                logic // unsure what to put here
                for(String key: initialMap.keySet()){
                   Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>> val = initialMap.get(key);                    
                   limitedMap.put(key,val);
                }                
            }
        }
        else{
            limitedMap.putAll(initialMap);
        }
```

Code after changes :

```
        System.debug('initialMap.size()::: '+initialMap.size());
    System.debug('requiredElements::: '+requiredElements);
        Map<String, Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>> limitedMap = new Map<String, Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>>();
        if(initialMap.size() > requiredElements){
            System.debug('inside if');
            Set<String> targetKeyset = new Set<String>();
            for(String key :initialMap.keySet()){
                if(requiredElements<= 0) { 
                    break; 
                }
                targetKeyset.add(key);
                requiredElements--;
            }
            System.debug('targetKeyset.size()::: '+targetKeyset.size());
            limitedMap = initialMap.clone();
            limitedMap.keySet().retainAll(targetKeyset);
        }
        else{
            limitedMap = initialMap.clone();
            System.debug('inside else');
        }
        System.debug('limitedMap.size()::: '+limitedMap.size());
        return limitedMap;
}
```

Comment: Maps and Sets have no intrinsic order, so you can't really get the first, middle, last, etc... You could get `n` elements, but since a Map is unordered you couldn't really say which elements they are. That aside, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DerekF I don't have to bother about the order but i need to get n elements from  the map and put in another map.

Comment: And what have you tried? [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: @DerekF I have edited the question. Kindly check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you're taking now requires that you can access map elements by an index like you can with a List. That's not possible.

For what you are trying to do, you need to work with the Map's Keyset. There are a few ways to go about doing this, but in general you'll need to

- Iterate over the keyset
- Keep track of how many times you've iterated

An example of how I might approach this:

```java
// Assume we have the following map, populated elsewhere in code
// The map's value type isn't terribly important, this approach should
//   apply no matter what the value type is
// Map<String, String> givenMap

Integer numElements = 5;

// Defining the keyset that we want to extract gives us a bit more
//   flexibility later on (at the cost of a little more code and
//   being a little harder to comprehend)
Set<String> targetKeyset = new Set<String>();

// Add keys to our set until we have the number we want
// The break; ensures that we don't waste cycles iterating
//   over things that we don't want to add to our target map
// If the givenMap contains fewer than numElements items, we simply add them
//   all (no extra/special logic required)
for(String key :givenMap.keySet()){
    if(numElements <= 0) { break; }
    targetKeyset.add(key);
    numElements--;
}

// Using clone() here has different effects based on the value type
// For primitive types (integers, strings, booleans, etc...) it creates an
//   independent copy
// For non-primitive types (any SObject, classes you've defined in Apex, 
//   other collections, etc...) it creates a reference.
// The difference being that if you have a reference, changing the value in
//   the targetMap will also change the value in the givenMap.
// If that's not what you want, then you can use deepClone() (if the value type is
//   an SObject)
Map<String, String> targetMap = givenMap.clone();
targetMap.keySet().retainAll(targetKeyset);
```

Comment: It is still showing all the elements.

Comment: @MakcM How is `requiredElements` being set in your code? Are you sure you've applied my example correctly?

Comment: `requiredElements` is being sent from LWC in the wire function dynamically. Yes absolutely I implemented all steps given by you.

Comment: @MakcM You should add a `system.debug()` to check what value you're getting from your LWC. It'd also be helpful if you edited your question to include the code you have now (add your new code to the question, but don't overwrite the old code).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Have I overlooked something in the question and its accepted reply? On the face of it, cloning a whole map just in order to copy the first 5 elements looks dodgy. Suggestion:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>> limitedMap 
    = new Map<String, Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>>();
Integer requiredElements = 5;
for (String key : originalMap.keySet()) {
    limitedMap.put(key, originalMap.get(key));
    if (requiredElements-- == 1)
        break;
}
```

(And just in order to pick up the discussion in the comments: [Since 2015](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/196/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer15_release_notes.pdf#page=261) Apex sets (incl. key sets) are ordered.)